# Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource at getTableUnknownDataSourceError

Tags: angular6, jsonparser, angular-material-6

I am new to Angular and Angular Material ,

> **Without Angular Materail it is working fine**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>City</th>  
    <th>State</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td>{{ varEmp?.address.city}}</td>
      <td>{{ varEmp?.address.state}}</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

> **With Angular Material it is not Working**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="varEmp" class="mat-elevation-z8">


  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> City</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.address.city}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> State</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.address.state}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**In component I declared variable**

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['city','state'];
```

briefy described component code to reduce complexity

> Json Object

```
{"address":
   {"city": "Karwar", "state": "Karnataka"}
}
```

Comment: Is the `datasource` of `mat-table` in your example, An object?

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this issue as I had a static data source of json format and I needed to dump it in a mat-table.

The most common reason for this behavior is poor format of json data. The json data expected by mat-table should be in the format `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`. If you cannot change the format of the json data, simply convert the data to Array like this

`var dataArr = new Array(jsonData));`

and it would work.

Note - Converting it to array would add an extra layer of square brackets to the data. You might need to change the `[dataSource]` property in mat-table to `dataArr[0]`.

`<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataArr[0]">`

Answer (score 2):

Define the datasource of table as ;

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Address>(this.addressList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data to an array.

[dataSource] for angular material mat-table, requires that an array of data is passed to it. Ensure that you have a well formatted array of your data before assigning to your data source

Answer (score 0):

You could try edit the **td** tag and do not use **?** after the **element**.
For example:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address.city}} </td>
```